# Bulk insert into oracle table with database/sql package not working

Tags: oracle, go

My requirement is to insert multiple rows into oracle table via database/sql pkg. Below is my code snippet, I have been trying:

```
   db, err := sql.Open("oracle", connectionUrl)
     if err != nil {
        e.logger.Error("Can't create connection: " + err.Error())
        return err
    }

    valueStrings := make([]string, 0, len(metrics))
    valueArgs := make([]interface{}, 0, len(metrics)*9)
    for _, post := range metrics {
        valueStrings = append(valueStrings, "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
        valueArgs = append(valueArgs, post.Timestamp)
        valueArgs = append(valueArgs, post.MetricName)
        valueArgs = append(valueArgs, post.MetricType)
        valueArgs = append(valueArgs, post.MetricUnit)
        valueArgs = append(valueArgs, post.MetricDescription)
        valueArgs = append(valueArgs, post.MetricValue)
        valueArgs = append(valueArgs, post.Host)
        valueArgs = append(valueArgs, post.ResourceAttributes)
        valueArgs = append(valueArgs, post.MetricAttributes)

    }

    sql := fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO my_table(TS, NAME, TYPE, UNIT, DESCRIPTION, VALUE, HOST, RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES, METRIC_ATTRIBUTES) VALUES %s",
        strings.Join(valueStrings, ","))
    logger.Info("#### Insert sql : " + sql)
    logger.Info("### ValueArgs :")
    fmt.Println(valueArgs)

    result, err := db.Exec(sql, valueArgs...)
    if err != nil {
    e.logger.Error("Bulk insert failed: " + err.Error())
    return err
    }
```

I could see db connection is successful and sql being successfully created as:

```
 INSERT INTO my_table(TS, NAME, TYPE, UNIT, DESCRIPTION, VALUE, HOST, RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES, METRIC_ATTRIBUTES) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?),(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?),(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?),(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?),(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

but while executing sql with valueArgs, it is returning error. Not getting any clue where the problem is.
Error log is:
Bulk insert failed: EOF    {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "oracle"}
Any suggestion to make edits to above code and make it work ?

Comment: Oracle does not support multiple tuples inside `values` clause

Comment: Is your Oracle version 23c? The *multilpe* [insert_values_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423__I2122346) is available only starting with this version. FYI @astentx ;)

Comment: "it is returning error" always include the error text.  Even if you think it's not relevant, and even if only to stop people like me from asking what it says.

Comment: What error is it returning?

Comment: Error log is :  Bulk insert failed: EOF {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "oracle"}

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, before version 23, `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...),(...),(...)` is not valid syntax. You can use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` or `INSERT ALL ...`

For example:

```go
valueStrings = append(valueStrings, "SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? FROM DUAL")
```

and

```go
sql := fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO my_table(TS, NAME, TYPE, UNIT, DESCRIPTION, VALUE, HOST, RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES, METRIC_ATTRIBUTES) %s",
        strings.Join(valueStrings, " UNION ALL "))
```

---

Looking at [this array insert example](https://medium.com/@guy.harrison/best-practices-go-and-oracle-eddbe316197c#f018), it looks like you could use something like:

*Note: I do not use GO so I am trying to adapt your code and provide you with a general idea; the syntax may be incorrect and you will need to correct it.*

```go
sql := "INSERT INTO my_table(TS, NAME, TYPE, UNIT, DESCRIPTION, VALUE, HOST, RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES, METRIC_ATTRIBUTES) VALUES (:ts, :mn, :mt, :mu, :md, :mv, :h, :ra, :ma)"

tsArgs := make([]interface{}, 0, len(metrics))
mnArgs := make([]interface{}, 0, len(metrics))
mtArgs := make([]interface{}, 0, len(metrics))
muArgs := make([]interface{}, 0, len(metrics))
mdArgs := make([]interface{}, 0, len(metrics))
mvArgs := make([]interface{}, 0, len(metrics))
hArgs := make([]interface{}, 0, len(metrics))
raArgs := make([]interface{}, 0, len(metrics))
maArgs := make([]interface{}, 0, len(metrics))

for _, post := range metrics {
    tsArgs = append(tsArgs, post.Timestamp)
    mnArgs = append(mnArgs, post.MetricName)
    mtArgs = append(mtArgs, post.MetricType)
    muArgs = append(muArgs, post.MetricUnit)
    mdArgs = append(mdArgs, post.MetricDescription)
    mvArgs = append(mvArgs, post.MetricValue)
    hArgs = append(hArgs, post.Host)
    raArgs = append(raArgs, post.ResourceAttributes)
    maArgs = append(maArgs, post.MetricAttributes)
}

result, err := db.Exec(sql, tsArgs, mnArgs, mtArgs, muArgs, mdArgs, mvArgs, hArgs, raArgs, maArgs)
if err != nil {
    e.logger.Error("Bulk insert failed: " + err.Error())
    return err
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I slightly modify in your suggestion and edited my code . Sql query is coming as  : INSERT INTO my_table(TS, NAME, TYPE, UNIT, DESCRIPTION, VALUE, HOST, RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES, METRIC_ATTRIBUTES) 
SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? AS my_table FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? AS my_table FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? AS my_table FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? AS my_table FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? AS my_table FROM DUAL   --> Manual inserts using this query is working fine

Comment: But still insertion via code is still failing with same error. Seems  db.Exec(sql, valueArgs...) is not placing the values correctly. I too  verified that tuples value for  valueArgs is fine.

Comment: @Rajat I can't help with the GO code as I do not use that language; you will need to wait for another answer for a GO expert for that. On the Oracle side, `? AS my_table FROM DUAL` is applying the `AS my_table` alias to the last `?` bind parameter and not to the table name; this is valid syntax but the alias is unnecessary and just using `? FROM DUAL` should give identical results.